# How to calculate row wise average for floats in list

Tags: python

I have below list and I am trying to calculate row wise averages for each row.

`print(hw_scores)`

```py
[9.0, 1.0, 1.9, 0.8666666666666667]
[0.0, 9.7, 0.76, 0.8333333333333334]
[0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9333333333333333]
```

I wrote the below code  but I am facing error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Code:

```py
row_avgs = []
for row in hw_scores:
    row_avgs.append(statistics.mean(row))
print(str(row_avgs))
```

The output should be something like

```py
[3.16,2.82,0.83]
```

Comment: Please include the exact way you define `hw_scores` as the error is most likely that you do not define it correctly as a 2d list

Comment: What line causes the error? Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: Note that your `hw_scores` block is not valid python. Or at least it doesn't do anything because you have 3 lists each on a separate line, but they are not assigned to any variable. Please show code that we can copy/paste and get the exact same error.

Comment: I just kept hw_scores as ‘hw_scores : ‘ to just say that this variable contains list like I have mentioned when I do print(hw_scores).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the correct sintax for 2D lists in Python when you define your variable `hw_scores`:

```
import statistics

hw_scores = [
    [9.0, 1.0, 1.9, 0.8666666666666667],
    [0.0, 9.7, 0.76, 0.8333333333333334],
    [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9333333333333333],
]

row_avgs = []
for row in hw_scores:
    row_avgs.append(statistics.mean(row))
print(str(row_avgs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first properly define a 2d list. Then you can use the statistics module to solve your problem. Modified code to print average of each row:

```
#Import the statistics module
import statistics

#Create a 2d list
hw_scores = [
    [9.0, 1.0, 1.9, 0.8666666666666667],
    [0.0, 9.7, 0.76, 0.8333333333333334],
    [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9333333333333333],
]

#Create a list to store the average values
score_avg = []

#Iterate over each list in hw_scores
for row in hw_scores:
    row_avg = statistics.mean(row) #statistics.mean will return the average of the values in one row

    score_avg.append(row_avg) #Add average value to the average values list
   
print(str(score_avg)) #Print the average values list as a string
```